# what is the time complexity for that piece of code?

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity, coding-style

what is the time complexity of this code?
how can I improve this code?

```
import random

n=input('choose one h/t? ')
v=random.randint(0,1)

if n=='h':
    if v==0:
        print('Hurrah!!! You win. Result is Head.')
    else:
        print('alas!!! You lose. Result is Tell.')
elif n=='t':
    if v==1:
        print('hurrah!!! You win. Result is Tell.')
    else:
        print('alas!!! You lose. Result is Head.')
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suitable for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you:

- either merge the h and v if to get one if only
- either determine first if it’s a h or t case, outside of other if. Then, use a function to test the other parts.

Indeed, just refactor to use functions as you are repeating yourself.